# Magento deletes orders after creating them

Tags: magento, braintree

Users purchase through our store, we get the money, licenses are delivered to the user, but the order is not visible in Magento. However, the orders are visible in Braintree. The order number increment show that the order was created at some point but it has been deleted by Magento for some reason.

Comment: are you using any extension , may be thats the reason....

Comment: We use Braintree extension but how could that cause this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: if you have any development or testing site, you can disable the braintree extension and check .....

Comment: well, the whole point is that I need to use BT! I made changes to capture($invoice) method but not sure if the strange behaviour could be related to my changes.